# Lists & Collections in MVVM - which approach to take?

Tags: mvvm

I'm currently working on a Silverlight app using Caliburn.Micro.

At present, we have Views (eg: `PeopleView`) and View Models (eg: `PeopleViewModel`) that equate to 'pages' of the application.

`PeopleView` might contain a `ListBox` ("`People`") which is bound to an `ObservableCollection` of `Person` objects, and has an `ItemTemplate` assigned to denote how each `Person` object should be displayed.

However, one of my colleagues has begun to implement a list in another way, where each `Person` is a View Model (ie: `PersonViewModel`) and has an associated `PersonView` to determine how that `PersonViewModel` should be displayed in the `ListBox`.

The latter seems more MVVM (or at least has more mention of V and VM!) but I'm not sure whether there's a particularly large advantage to doing one over the other.

Are both of these ways valid? Is either better than the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, both ways are valid. There are pros and cons to each approach.

If the `Person` can be displayed in several different ways depending on the context - whether it's in a `ListBox` or on a "page" then using your technique with an `ItemTemplate` to control how it's displayed in the list is probably the better way to go.

I think you need to look at your overall design and see which fits best. Changing the implementation part way through is a bad idea though. Some "pages" will be the old style and others will be the new, leading to inconsistencies in the user experience and potentially increased effort in maintaining and extending the system. If nothing else, you will have to go through the existing code to make it conform to the new format.

Comment: Thanks Chris - the `Person` can be displayed in different ways, yes.  I believe there's a way to associate multiple Views with a single ViewModel but I haven't looked too far into that.  I agree with your last paragraph - although in this instance the UX would be the same, the code would have two possible implementations rather than one, which is about one too many for this particular scenario!

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so assuming `Person` is your entity (model object)...

You can do it either way, but with some caveat's:

1) Binding directly to a model object works well in read-only screens.  If you just return a list of `People` and you want the user to choose one, great, it's easy to just bind to that list.

2) Binding directly to your domain model can start to suck if you're implementing a screen that allows you to manipulate those objects.  The state of the data under edit [can represent an invalid model state until validated and saved](http://www.contactandcoil.com/software/editing-logic-is-business-logic/).

Due to #2, a lot of people make a `PersonViewModel` that's really for editing.  I don't think that's a good idea either.  I think you need to define model classes that represent the state during the editing (and mapping operations between the `Person` and `PersonEdit` classes, including validation).

Now if you want to go adding a `PersonViewModel`, it does have some advantages.  Let's say your `Person` has a property `DateOfBirth` and a derived property `Age`, and another derived property `AgeGroup` (perhaps Toddler, Preteen, Teen, etc.).  What if you want to display those people highlighted different colors based on their age group?  You can either define a `ValueConverter` (if you still want to bind directly to the `Person` object), or you can wrap the `Person` object in a `PersonViewModel` and add an `AgeGroupColor` property to the view model.  Then you can bind directly to that.  Which method you choose is really up to you.  A lot of people don't like `ValueConverters`, and I agree they're a little verbose for what they do, so I'd probably go with the view model option, like your friend.

Comment: Cheers Scott.  `AgeGroupColour` in this scenario sounds to me more like something that should be defined in the View, as it's purely cosmetic.  Although it's restricted to two states, I've generally used [`DataStateBehavior`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff723952(v=expression.40).aspx) to achieve this in the item's DataTemplate based on model properties, and I think this type of idea could be extended in [this way](http://blogs.infosupport.com/blogs/alexb/archive/2010/04/02/silverlight-4-using-the-visualstatemanager-for-state-animations-with-mvvm.aspx), although I could be wrong!

Comment: @Town: It's not that well defined.  If the `ViewModel` is a testable representation of the `View`, you might have a unit test which cares that `AgeGroup.Teen` is displayed as `Colors.Red` so you'd want it in the `ViewModel`.  In my opinion, you want as little "logic" in the `View` as possible.

Comment: That's true Scott, although if we were writing tests to confirm that something was a particular colour in the UI then we'd probably be here forever! I get what you're saying though and it's an example that I'm sure would be very relevant for other similar scenarios that aren't so trivial as UI colours. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

There's no point having a `PersonViewModel` if it doesn't have any additional properties over and above the `Person` model. It's just a waste of time.

However, if you're using value converters to convert a `Person` in any way then I'd have used a `PersonViewModel` and not bothered with the value converter.

`PersonViewModel` should simply expose the `Person` object and any additional properties. I wouldn't proxy every single `Person` property into the `PersonViewModel`.

Comment: Cheers Ben, that confirms what Scott said about extending the underlying class with additional properties, and also explains why you hate ValueConverters so much.

Answer (score 0):

If person is in your model, then it seems to violate the separation created by only exposing view model to the view.

My general rule is the ability to create the viewmodel and view without a model.  If this can not be accomplished I make changes.

Exposing the Model to the view is perfectly valid, but it is more of a MVC pattern.